# What is the proper way to hide/cancel a react-native Android Toast after the App has closed

Tags: react-native, android-toast

I use the react-router library and the history props to navigate through my react-native application. If the user is not on the StartPage a click on backpress on an android device will navigate him to the StartPage. If the user already is on the StartPage a backpress leads to a toast (AndroidToast from 'react-native') with a message "click again to close". The time between two clicks on backpress is won by a simple timestamp.

```
    if(this.props.history.location.pathname !== "/start") {
      this.props.history.push("/start")
    }

    else {

      if ((moment().diff(this.state.backPressTimeStamp)) <= 1500) {
        // this.setState({
        //   visible: false
        // })
        BackHandler.exitApp()
      }

      else {
        this.setState({
          backPressTimeStamp: moment(),
          visible: true,
        }, () => {
          this.hideToast();
        })
      }
    }
    return true
  }
```

the toast is returned by a function which is called inside the render method (ios = no backpress)

```
  loadToast = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      return (
          this.state.visible && <View>
            <Toast
              visible={this.state.visible}
              duration={ToastAndroid.SHORT}
              gravity={ToastAndroid.BOTTOM}
              x_offset={0}
              y_offset={125}
              message={"click again to close"}
            />
          </View>
      )
    }
    else {
      return null
    }
  }
```

[....]

```
render() {
 return(
  ...
  {this.loadToast()}
  ...
 )
}
```

Everything is working like it is suppose to, but i can't seem to figure out how to hide/close the Toast once the App is closed. It keeps being visible for the duration, no matter if the visible value is set to false / the hideToast function is called.

Any ideas on how to force the toast to hide/close once the App is closed would be highly appreciated!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda late and maybe you figured it out but have you tried to use directly the SimpleToast.show instead of a component ?

```
import SimpleToast from 'react-native-simple-toast';
SimpleToast.show(message, SimpleToast.SHORT);
```

and you have to set it explicitly to SimpleToast.SHORT/LONG on iOS so it hides automatically.